# PHP not echoing every content of my array passed in JSON encode

Tags: php

I am trying to display the contents of collections (4 items) randomly. I works perfectly except that the first 3 items show but the last 2 items in the array don't, I always get a blank echo. Why is this happening?

```
$sql = "SELECT test FROM sandbox";

$collections = [];

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
      $collections[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode(array('test'=>$collections[rand(0, count($collections))]));
}
```

**Edit:**

- Var_dump shows that everything is fetched and stored in the array
- No error logs
- Records have a Kollation of utf8_unicode_ci
- Strings with umlauts are neither shown with json encode nor with normal strings such as "echo Ö". The latter gives me Ã

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I always get a blank echo". Certainly the echo is not _completely_ "blank", since it should show the array notation. Please add more details to your question: 1. the values stored in the database and 2. the output you describe.

Comment: Just a really wild guess, though you hopefully considered that yourself already: remember that the browser will try to interpret the output as html, not as plain text, so you'd have to escape the shown values if they contain html tags...

Comment: @arkascha it is truly empty, no jokes. Even when checking out the dom tree

Comment: That would mean that `json_encode()` fails. Please check your http servers error log file. Though I doubt that really is the issue here. Something is "fishy" here...

Comment: @arkascha im testing on a localhost with XAMPP. I mean everything else works except those last 2.

Comment: That is fine, but not of interest. What does your error log file say and please add the details as I asked.

Comment: @arkascha will google how to access the logs. Never done that before. Hang on

Comment: You cannot program php scripts in a web environment without looking at the log files! It is the error log file your local http server writes. The location is configured in your http servers configuration.

Comment: @arkascha [:error] [pid 2644:tid 1660] [client ::1:50485] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/sandbox/index.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: @arkascha that is the youngest error but that was 4 hours ago.

Comment: A `json_encode()` call receiving an array as argument will output a string that is not empty. So either the echo is not executed at all, or the script crashes. Maybe you want to output some small static string before and after the `json_encode()` call to check that.

Comment: Oh, and another question: is the code you posted _really_ the exact code you are using?

Comment: Have you tried var_dump(yourArray) to check if results are being fetched?

Comment: @arkascha yes, the exact code. In the database I only have 5 records (text) with some strings, nothing fancy. The program retrieves them and stores them in the array. You might want to check it out.

Comment: @SaqibOmer yes, not with var_dump but with a foreach. I will do it either way now just to be on the safe side

Comment: I still cannot see the details I asked you to add to the question twice.

Comment: @SaqibOmer results are being fetched.

Comment: @arkascha I will do that now: "Maybe you want to output some small static string before and after the json_encode() call to check that" Which details do you need?

Comment: @arkascha  echo json_encode(array('test'=>$collections[rand(0, count($collections)-1)])) + "World"; returns 0

Comment: One more time, just as asked in the very first comment: _Please add more details to your question: 1. the values stored in the database and 2. the output you describe._ Be precise in your questions.

Comment: Problem could be in the values also. If it contains some special characters, that will get truncated while displaying.. So, check your values which gives problem..

Comment: @arkascha I had german umlaute like ö Ä that is why it failed. How can I fix this? I thought I used utf-8

Comment: `json_encode()` does not have issues with Umlauts. Also a "fail" should result in an error. So again: _be precise_ in your statements. What does "fail" mean here? How are those Umlauts stored, so how is your database, table and connection configured? And why do you silently refuse to post the information we asked for?

Comment: @arkascha Fail means nothing gets echoed. I will put some database info in my question

Comment: @arkascha added two more points in my question. Records have a Kollation of utf8_unicode_ci.
Strings with umlauts are neither shown with json encode nor with normal strings such as "echo Ö". The latter gives me Ã

Comment: I am out, sorry. 1. there is a _huge_ difference between "nothing gets echoed" and "`Ö` is visualized as `Ã`". Second: you _still_ do not react to all the requests to provide specific information. 3. If the call to `json_encode()` really crashes (which is indicated by the "0" output of your attempts with static strings), then there is an entry in the error log file, _except if you disabled error logging_. Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your database connection does not use UTF-8. That's why `json_encode` fails - it only works with UTF-8 encoded characters.

Try to issue a

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

before querying your table. Or use `mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8')` when using the `mysqli` extension.

And as others have already indicated, it should be

```
count($collections) - 1
```

because `rand()` takes the lowest and the highest value to return as its function arguments. But `count($collections)` is not a valid index on an array of length `count($collections)`.

Comment: I will try that. I previously used utf8_encode but that didnt work

Comment: Did that via phpmyadmin but nothing changed when I tested my code again

Comment: You cannot do that via phpmyadmin. You have to do that on the connection used to query the data. This is a per connection setting.

Comment: you mean the sql string?

Comment: Ah it works now but the umlauts show their ASCII characters instead L\u00f6

Comment: How do you know that it's "ASCII" (ASCII does not support extended characters)?

Comment: I think it was called unicode right? So I now get the unicode representation and not the actual character.

Answer (score -1):

**I guess your problem lies in code of yours,**

```
rand(0, count($collections))])
```

When you run `rand()` within range of `array length` and `array length` times for instance 0 and 4 who says that you don't get `rand()` result as 2,2,3,4 which means you randomize selects one key multiple times.